# How to execute a bitbake task after do_rootfs of other recipe is finished?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Whenever do_rootfs of `bitbake core-image-minimal` has finished executing I want to execute my custom task.

I created a task my-task.bb in meta-xxx/recipes-core/meta:

```
INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS = "1"

inherit native

deltask do_fetch
deltask do_unpack
deltask do_patch
deltask do_configure
deltask do_compile
deltask do_install
deltask do_populate_sysroot

python do_something() {
    bb.error("Executed")
}

addtask something

do_something[nostamp] = "1"
```

I also created `core-image-minimal.bbappend` and put the following into it:

`do_core-image-mimimal[depends] = "my-task:do_something"`

But do_something is not executed when I do `bitbake core-image-minimal`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want to define a shell function and add it to ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND (c.f. https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND).